# Azure Databrics - Running a Spark Jar from Gen2 DataLake Storage

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I am trying to run a spark-submit from Azure Databrics. Currently I can create a job, with the jar uploaded within the Databrics workspace, and run it.

My queries are:

1. Is there a way to access a jar residing on a GEN2 DataLake storage and do a spark-submit from Databrics workspace, or even from Azure ADF ? (Because the communication between the workspace and GEN2 storage is protected "fs.azure.account.key")
2. Is there a way to do a spark-submit from a databrics notebook?

Comment: you can schedule databricks notebook. See  https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/jobs.html#run-a-job and https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html

Comment: I have already done that. (I wrote in the first line.) I am looking for a way to do points 1 and 2 specifically. Could you suggest or comment on that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I figured out how to run this:

1. You can do a run a Databricks jar from an ADF, and attach it to an existing cluster, which will have the adls key configured in the cluster.
2. It is not possible to do a spark-submit from a notebook. But you can create a spark job in jobs, or you can use the [Databricks Run Sumbit](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-submit) api, to do a spark-submit.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to access a jar residing on a GEN2 DataLake storage and
>   do a spark-submit from Databrics workspace, or even from Azure ADF ?
>   (Because the communication between the workspace and GEN2 storage is
>   protected "fs.azure.account.key") Unfortunately, you cannot access a
>   jar residing on Azure Storage such as ADLS Gen2/Gen1 account.

**Note:** The --jars, --py-files, --files arguments support **DBFS** and **S3** paths.

Typically, the Jar libraries are stored under dbfs:/FileStore/jars.

You need to upload libraries in dbfs and pass as the parameters in the jar activity.

For more details, refer "[Transform data by running a jar activity in Azure Databricks using ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-jar)".

> Is there a way to do a spark-submit from a databricks notebook?

To answer the second question, you may refer the below Job types:

[image]

Reference: [SparkSubmit](https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/jobs.html#jobssparksubmittask) and "[Create a job](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/jobs.html#create-a-job)"

Hope this helps.

---

If this answers your query, do click “Mark as Answer” and "Up-Vote" for the same. And, if you have any further query do let us know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my post I mentioned that I am already able to do this. Wanted to look for a way to do a normal Spark-submit as we do from scripts, or Jupyter notebooks.